# Meaning of "a liver snap"?

Tags: word-usage

I watched an episode of "Friends" where Phoebe says to Mike:

> "...scratch her tummy and give her ***a liver snap***."

I don't understand "a liver snap".

What does "a liver snap" mean here?

Comment: Are they possibly talking about a dog? I'd imagine that a liver snap is like a [ginger snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger_snap), which is a type of biscuit, but liver flavored.

Comment: [Liver Snaps dog treats](http://dogpacksnacks.net/2011/11/liver-snaps/)

Comment: maybe it's a metaphor. I am wondering what snap means in "a ginger snap?" 'cause I look up in dictionary, it isn't relevant to biscuit. or it's just a brand name?

Comment: Did you click on the link in vpn´s comment relevant to "ginger snaps"?

Comment: It's a joke. I don't precisely know the characters but if I remember right, Phoebe says some sort of "out there" things that are sort of simple but "slightly off" approaches. If I'm guessing right maybe she's suggesting to be nice to her(whoever that is) like he would be nice to a dog(scratch them and give them a treat) to make the dog enjoy his company? And of course, Phoebe probably isn't saying that seriously, and might be playing on a prior line, or teasing Mike about 'puppy love" or something else context would give you.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yes, the Liver Snap is a dog treat. She may be saying to treat a girl like a pet dog because she sounds like a dog. That's an old harsh and sexist term for not pretty enough.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I only threw that out there for the OP to include to show they had done _some_ research. They still have not edited to make it clear whether it was the phrase, or the usage in context they were having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two seconds on Google found top ranged hits similar to 
http://www.candyssweetlife.com/for-the-dogs-liver-snaps/ 
So, it's a dog treat.